# How JavaScript resolves value of object property?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say we have the following object:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 4,
  d: 13
};
```

And then we try to access a property of it:

```
obj.d
```

How is this done? I can imagine 2 ways:

1. traversal of all key-value pairs each time we try to get value of object (meaning that if we would do `obj.d`, we would traverse all previous keys of `obj` sequentially) - meaning complexity of this operation for object with n keys is `O(n)`;
2. some axillary tree-like structure is there for each object, so getting value for some key is done faster then with `O(n)`

There might be some optimizations, like storing all keys in some order, so we can live without axillary structure. But questions still holds: **How JavaScript resolves value of object property?**

Comment: The spec does not stipulate any particular implementation, but generally it's something like a hashing scheme that's *heavily* optimized.

Comment: I don't believe this is specified. It depends on each implementation.